# Is there a way using a poorly documented/abandoned REST API to query the required parameters and datatypes for a particular function?

Tags: json, rest, post

I'm trying to create an app for the animal shelter I work for that would allow adopters to fill out their adoption application via an iPad, which would then update our adoption database with their contact info. The adoption database software we use is called ShelterBuddy, and they have an API available, but it looks to be very-poorly documented and sort of abandoned, and all attempts to connect with support or the original creators have gone nowhere. A lot of the functions I have gotten to work have been through trial and error because the little documentation that is provided is incorrect, probably being outdated.

There is a function for creating a person, using a JSON post request, that I've been trying for weeks and can't get to work - I kept getting a generic "200 bad request" and kept adding more and more info, until finally I got a more specific error:

> "{"Message":"The argument cannot be null"}"

So I feel like I am close but I don't know what is null - is there a generic way to query a function in a REST API to pull from the API itself what fields for a function are required and what their required datatypes are? I am guessing that there isn't but just wanted to check before giving up on this project.

I can post more specific details if needed.

Comment: you mean: https://demo.shelterbuddy.com/api/v2/documentation.aspx ?

Comment: or: https://shelterbuddy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SbApi/pages/85098501/FAQ+Common+Issues#What-is-an-example-of-saving-a-person%3F ?

Comment: Yes I've gone through all of that documentation with a fine tooth comb but a lot of information is missing and I am seeing evidence that the documentation is outdated. Pulling data I've mostly gotten to work but with a lot of trial and error that is different from the documentation, but updating records I've had very little success with, and inserting new records I haven't gotten to work at all - I've added every parameter possible, even trying out different data types, and I can only reach a generic "argument cannot be null" error message, and no way to find out what is null